# jQuery.verto is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, jquery-plugins, vue-cli

I'm using a [Verto library](https://evoluxbr.github.io/verto-docs/tut/initializing-verto.html) in my Vue-CLI based project - I've copied all necessary files to my `static` folder and imported it directly as a files in my `index.html` file - something like this:

```
<script src="static/js/jquery.min.js"></script> // I've also tried with including jQuery in webpack config, but with the same result
<script src="static/js/jquery.json.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/jquery.verto.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/jquery.FSRTC.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/jquery.jsonrpcclient.js"></script>
```

And in my component's methods I have something like this:

```
connectAudio () {
  /* eslint-disable new-cap */
  const verto = new jQuery.verto({
  ...
```

But once I execute it, I receive an error: `"TypeError: jQuery.verto is not a constructor"`

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're calling `new jQuery.verto({})` inside the verto init callback as the docs suggest.

Example: `$.verto.init({}, function(){ ... new jQuery.verto({...}) ... })`.

Not sure if you're already doing it, I can't tell by the code snippet you shared.

Comment: thanks a lot! during the prototyping I've wanted to run it outside the verto's init callback (as the docs suggested) - that solved the problem!