# about electron-vue jQuery.verto is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, electron-vue

I'm using a Verto library in my Vue-electron based project.

In my component's methods I have something like this:

```
function newVerto () {
  vertoHandle = new jQuery.verto({
    ...
  }, vertoCallbacks)
}
```

But once I execute it, I receive an error:

> "TypeError: jQuery.verto is not a constructor"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery.verto is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50910562/jquery-verto-is-not-a-constructor)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you mean.